# Is it correct way of displaying Image from .NET Core API in ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core API that returns an image:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult GetImage()
 {
     return File("Image bytes", "image/jpeg");
 }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync("uri");

    var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    var imgSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);            

    var model = new ImageData { ImageSrc = imgSrc };

    return View(model);
}
```

And in the view, I just pass the image source to `img` element.

Everything works fine, but is it the correct way of doing it?

The API returns the response that has `FileContentResult`. Is there a way to render that result without converting it to Base64 string and do what I am doing?

Appreciate any comments.

Comment: So the `Controller` is in an ASP.NET (.NET Framework) project separate from your .NET Core API which actually returns an image? Is there a reason why you can't just use the image direct from the .NET Core API in an `<img src="blah">` tag? And is there a reason why you're not using the [Static File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) functionality of ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Images are stored outside of the MVC Web Application and transferred throug API. So I cannot use them directly.

Comment: Do you mean that there's some authentication step? What stops you using them directly?

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't know how to use them directly and that's why i came up with the above solution.

Comment: `<img src="https://www.example.com/controller/getImage">` ? As in put your `"uri"` value in `src`.

Comment: Yep, this works well. Thank you! Would you recomment to return PhysicalFile instead of File in the API?

Comment: Possibly, though if you're using `PhysicalFile`, perhaps the static file functionality of ASP.NET Core (as I linked above) would be more suitable to your use case.

Comment: Thanks John. If you answer this question I will mark it as accepted. Cheers

Comment: I have done. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API code is simply returning an image as any other web server would (from the client's perspective), so unless there's some authentication step that you haven't shown, you should be able to simply use the endpoint URL directly in an `img` tag.

Take your `"uri"` value and insert it into an image tag on your rendered page:

```
<img src="uri">
```

For example, if your uri is https://www.example.com/controller/getImage then you would end up with:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/controller/getImage">
```

Then the browser will directly connect to your API server to pull the image.

Incidentally, if you're just trying to serve local files from your ASP.NET Core API, you might be interested in using the built-in [static file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) functionality instead:

> Static files, such as HTML, CSS, images, and JavaScript, are assets an ASP.NET Core app serves directly to clients by default.